# UE 5.1 - Camera sets at zero coordinates while rendering

Tags: render, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I'm just started learning Unreal Engine and still can make some obvious mistakes. And I strongly don't understand why `when I render video, camera moves to zero coordinates.`

I made a Sequence, where my camera simply moves from one position to other. But when I go to Movie Render Queue, choose this sequence, and render local - it renders frames as if camera was on `zero` coordinates, and doesn't move.

Sequences

[image: 1]

[Camera moves to zero coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8OxD.png)

I made everything like in tutorials I watched, but nothing helped.

Do you know why this can happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first if you marked the keyframes right if so check this tutorial on how to use cameras and keyframes in U5.1

https://youtu.be/6fRc6PXw2Zs

Note: if the problem still appers it could be a U5.1 Bug since its shortly released.

Comment: I downloaded UE5, and it looks great here. Probably it is UE5.1 bug.